# An online web tool to export SVG (as raw code) into other image formats

Tags: web-apps, media-converter, svg, png

I'm very interested in SVGs, and I regularly write them as raw code on my iPad. My *managed* iPad—I can only install a specific list of whitelisted apps.

If I want to, for example, upload it to a website that doesn't support/allow SVGs, this is the fastest method that I know:

1. Email the code to myself.
2. Log on to my home computer (for time on which I compete with my 2 brothers).
3. Convert the code to an SVG file there—I need to use an ASCII->hex converter and then a hex->downloadable file converter for this.
4. *Now* I can convert it into a PNG.
5. Sometimes I'm using something that the converter doesn't support, such as anonymous filters. In this case I have to backtrack, replace it with a workaround, and repeat steps 3 and 4 to fix it.

I'm really annoyed by having to do this every time. Is there an online tool to directly convert SVG code into a PNG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Website Checker](http://websitechecker.io/tools/svg-png-jpeg-base64-image-converter/) site allows you to simply paste the text of your raw SVG into a box and then preview & download the resulting image as PNG or JPEG.

Answer (score 0):

[Image Magick Studio](http://transloadit.imagemagick.org/MagickStudio/scripts/MagickStudio.cgi) is an online instance of Image Magick and handily handles conversion of of .svg files to lots of formats with lots of options.

- Price: Free
- Can directly upload to another site rather than downloading to your device then you uploading.
- You can scale, rotate, colourise, etc.
- Caviat - you must **View** your image after selecting it before doing anything else - even though that is not the next tab from Input.

Comment: But I can't upload my file as raw code—that's why I posted my question in the first place. (Before you ask, yes I tried the `data:` URI scheme.) Also, you spelled "conversion" wrong.

Comment: @StephenLeppik - Raw, or any format of SVG, is a text format - you should just be able to rename your raw file to .svg and then upload it to the web page.

Comment: The reason I came here was so that I could do the entire process on my iPad. This is just like the first page of Google results—it only accepts an uploaded file (I can't save an SVG to Photo Library) or an image URL (which doesn't accept `data:` URIs).